# The argument type 'T Function<T>(ProviderListenable<T>)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Reader<dynamic, dynamic>

Tags: flutter, riverpod

im trying to declare a provider for addmealChangenotifier but i notice on `ref.read` i keep on getting the erro `cant be assigned to the parameter type Reader` how can i go about fixing this error

```
final addMealProvider =
    ChangeNotifierProvider((ref) => AddMealChangeNotifier(ref.read ));

class AddMealChangeNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  final Reader _reader;
  AddMealChangeNotifier(this._reader);
```

Comment: Reader has gone away in Riverpod 2.  Just use Ref.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try it this way:

```dart
final addMealProvider =
    ChangeNotifierProvider((ref) => AddMealChangeNotifier(ref));

// or use tear-off
final addMealProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider(AddMealChangeNotifier.new);

class AddMealChangeNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  final Ref _ref;
  AddMealChangeNotifier(this._ref);
```

Also, you can define a custom Reader (not recommended):

```dart
typedef Reader = T Function<T>(ProviderBase<T> provider);
```

Mark it as correct if the answer helped you.